# Can connect to Redis with hostname, but not URL

Tags: python, redis, celery

I'm trying to connect Celery to a Redis backend on a different machine but I get a no route to host error. Removing Celery from the problem, I can connect with the redis client using hostname, but I get the same no route to host error using a redis url.

I tried creating 2 connection objects 1 using each method and both appear similar:

```py
>>> import redis
>>>
>>> r = redis.Redis(host='server.domain.com',port=6379)
>>> r2 = redis.Redis.from_url('redis://server.domain.com:6379')
>>>
>>> r
Redis<ConnectionPool<Connection<host=server.domain.com,port=6379,db=0>>>
>>> r2
Redis<ConnectionPool<Connection<host=server.domain.com,port=6379,db=0>>>
```

The hostname version works as expected:

```py
>>> r.get('test')
b'Test stuff'
```

But the version using the redis url returns the "no route to host" error:

```py
>>> r2.get('test')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 264, in connect
    sock = self.retry.call_with_retry(
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/retry.py", line 46, in call_with_retry
    return do()
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 265, in <lambda>
    lambda: self._connect(), lambda error: self.disconnect(error)
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 627, in _connect
    raise err
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 615, in _connect
    sock.connect(socket_address)
OSError: [Errno 113] No route to host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/commands/core.py", line 1829, in get
    return self.execute_command("GET", name)
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 533, in execute_command
    conn = self.connection or pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 1086, in get_connection
    connection.connect()
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 270, in connect
    raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 113 connecting to server.domain.com:6379. No route to host.
```

---

**Update**

Progress. I dug a little deeper into the redis objects and it seems the from_url method leaves out several kwargs when it creates the connection_pool:

```py
>>> r.connection_pool.__dict__
{'connection_class': <class 'redis.connection.Connection'>, 'connection_kwargs': {'db': 0, 'username': None, 'password': None, 'socket_timeout': None, 'encoding': 'utf-8', 'encoding_errors': 'strict', 'decode_responses': True, 'retry_on_error': [], 'retry': None, 'health_check_interval': 0, 'client_name': None, 'lib_name': 'redis-py', 'lib_version': '5.0.1', 'redis_connect_func': None, 'credential_provider': None, 'protocol': 2, 'host': 'server.domain.com', 'port': 6379, 'socket_connect_timeout': None, 'socket_keepalive': None, 'socket_keepalive_options': None}, 'max_connections': 2147483648, '_fork_lock': <unlocked _thread.lock object at 0x7fcfd576ebc0>, '_lock': <unlocked _thread.lock object at 0x7fcfd576d2c0>, '_created_connections': 1, '_available_connections': [Connection<host=server.domain.com,port=6379,db=0>], '_in_use_connections': set(), 'pid': 37317}
>>> r2.connection_pool.__dict__
{'connection_class': <class 'redis.connection.Connection'>, 'connection_kwargs': {'host': 'server.domain.com', 'port': 6379, 'db': 0}, 'max_connections': 2147483648, '_fork_lock': <unlocked _thread.lock object at 0x7fcfd5d6bb40>, '_lock': <unlocked _thread.lock object at 0x7fcfd5d6bbc0>, '_created_connections': 1, '_available_connections': [Connection<host=server.domain.com,port=6379,db=0>], '_in_use_connections': set(), 'pid': 37317}
```

This fixes the connection for the standalone redis client, but doesn't seem to work for Celery, same error there:

```py
>>> r2 = redis.Redis.from_url('redis://:@server.domain.com:6379')
>>> r2.get('test')
b'Test stuff'
```

Comment: Which version of the redis python package are you using?

Comment: 5.0.1
I got Redis to work by itself by adding :@ to the beginning of the url to force it to add the empty username and password to the connection, but that change didn't help with Celery (5.3.6).

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering with connecting to the Redis backend using a URL format in Python suggests a subtle difference in how the redis.Redis.from_url method interprets the URL compared to the standard hostname and port approach.

Given that the direct hostname and port approach works fine (redis.Redis(host='server.domain.com', port=6379)), but the URL approach (redis.Redis.from_url('redis://server.domain.com:6379')) results in a "No route to host" error.

You could try URL Parsing in order to solve your errors: The from_url method may be parsing the URL differently. Double-check the format of the URL. Make sure there are no typos or unintended characters. It should be in the format redis://server.domain.com:6379.

Comment: I've been trying to step through how the from_url method is creating the connection in the redis module, but haven't made any breakthroughs yet.